# Stdout and flush? It's appending and not flushing

Tags: python

What I'm trying to do is have some 'progress text' on the bottom of a script that I've creating. If I for loop a list [1,2,3,4,5] and print i, then it simply prints 1,2,3,4, and 5 on separate lines. How about if I want to print 1 out to the screen, sleep 5 seconds, clear that out and then print 2?

I've tried using stdout.write("text"), sleep, flush, stdout.write("aetlkjetjer"), sleep, and it just simply adds on to that "text" statement instead of flushing the output.

Am I misunderstanding something with the way stdout.flush works? Isn't it supposed to flush/erase the output of the previous print?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All `.flush()` does is flush out the buffer. What you actually want is to write backspace(`\b`) to `stdout`.

```
import time, sys

for i in [1,2,3,4,5]:
    sys.stdout.write(str(i))
    sys.stdout.flush() #flush the buffer because python buffers stdout
    time.sleep(5)
    sys.stdout.write("\b") #literally "write backspace".
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

It gets more complicated if you want to count up to numbers with more than one digit.

Answer (score 3):

In computer science, the term "flush" doesn't mean to erase what's already in a buffer; rather, it means to take the *unwritten* contents of a buffer in memory (like the stdout buffer) and write it, in this case to the screen. So when you tell the program to "flush stdout", you're really just telling it to "take what's in stdout and make sure it's all displayed on the screen."

Comment: thanks a lot for your help! this clarifies exactly the confusion that i had going on